# DirectX11 program bug full screen

Tags: directx, directx11, fullscreen, dxgi

I have a problem switching the engine from full screen to normal. I use alt + enter. The problem is this: when I start the engine in full screen and press alt + enter - it hangs. For mode of the screen corresponds to the flag *modeScreen*.
Below there is a video showing the work:

[youtube.com](https://youtu.be/KRs5utu8eI8)

This link has a minimal example.
First, start in normal mode and switch, and everything works well. Then start up in full screen and when switching the problem.

As you can see, when you start in full screen and try to change the screen mode, it hangs. How to overcome it?

The minimal complete verifiable example:

```
// headers
#include <windows.h>

#include <d3d11.h>

#include <string>

// libraries
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")

// global variable
IDXGISwapChain* swapChain(nullptr);
ID3D11Device* device(nullptr);
ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext(nullptr);
ID3D11RenderTargetView* backBuffer(nullptr);
ID3D11Texture2D* DepthStancil(nullptr);
ID3D11DepthStencilView* DepthStancilBuffer(nullptr);
ID3D11RasterizerState* rasterizer(nullptr);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth; 
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV; 
D3D11_VIEWPORT vp; 

// governors variable
int height(1080); // h window
int width(1920); // w window
bool modeScreen(false); // mode screen(true - full screen, false - windowed mode)

// constants windows message
#define WM_RENDER WM_USER + 1001

// functions
LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void createDescsTarget(int w, int h);
bool createTargetRender(int w, int h);
bool renderStateEdit(const D3D11_FILL_MODE& fm);
bool resizeWindow(SIZE p);
void renderEditor();

// main
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, 
    HINSTANCE hPrev,                
    LPSTR szCmdLine,                
    int nShowCmd)                   
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {0};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcx.hInstance = hInst;  
    wcx.lpszClassName = TEXT("Win32 DirectX");

    if ( !RegisterClassEx(&wcx) ) 
        return 1;
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        TEXT("Win32 DirectX"),
        TEXT("Test going to full screen DirectX programm"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,0,
        width,height,
        0, 
        0,
        hInst,
        0);

    if (!hWnd)    
        return 2;

    // init dx
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sdesc;
    ZeroMemory(&sdesc, sizeof(sdesc));
    sdesc.BufferCount = 1;
    sdesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sdesc.Windowed = true;
    sdesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH; 
    sdesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sdesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    sdesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sdesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

    UINT flags(NULL);
#ifdef DEBUG
    flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT;
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL, flags, levels, 8, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sdesc,
        &swapChain, &device, NULL, &deviceContext);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return 2;

    createDescsTarget(width, height);
    if (!createTargetRender(width, height))
        return 2;
    if (!renderStateEdit(D3D11_FILL_MODE::D3D11_FILL_SOLID))
        return 2;

    hr = swapChain->SetFullscreenState(modeScreen, nullptr);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return 2;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    MSG msg;
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
        else
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_RENDER, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return( (int)msg.wParam );  
}


LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        SIZE p;
        p.cx = LOWORD(lParam);
        p.cy = HIWORD(lParam);
        if (p.cx == 0 || p.cy == 0)
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        }
        if (!resizeWindow(p))
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_RENDER, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }

    case WM_RENDER:
        renderEditor();
        break;

    } 
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void createDescsTarget(int w, int h)
{
    ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(descDepth));
    descDepth.Width = w;
    descDepth.Height = h;
    descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
    descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&descDSV, sizeof(descDSV));
    descDSV.Format = descDepth.Format;
    descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    vp.Width = (float)w;
    vp.Height = (float)h;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
}

bool createTargetRender(int w, int h)
{
    ID3D11Texture2D* texture(nullptr);
    HRESULT hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&texture);
    hr = device->CreateRenderTargetView(texture, NULL, &backBuffer);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    texture->Release();

    if (DepthStancil)
        DepthStancil->Release();
    if (DepthStancilBuffer)
        DepthStancilBuffer->Release();

    hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &DepthStancil);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    hr = device->CreateDepthStencilView(DepthStancil, &descDSV, &DepthStancilBuffer);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;

    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backBuffer, DepthStancilBuffer);
    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);

    return true;
}

bool renderStateEdit(const D3D11_FILL_MODE& fm)
{
    if (rasterizer)
        rasterizer->Release();
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC wfd;
    ZeroMemory(&wfd, sizeof wfd);
    wfd.FillMode = fm;
    wfd.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    wfd.DepthClipEnable = true;
    HRESULT hr = device->CreateRasterizerState(&wfd, &rasterizer);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool resizeWindow(SIZE p)
{
    HRESULT hr(S_OK);

    int w = p.cx;
    int h = p.cy;

    width = w;
    height = h;

    descDepth.Width = w;
    descDepth.Height = h;
    vp.Width = (float)w;
    vp.Height = (float)h;

    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0); 
    backBuffer->Release();

    hr = swapChain->ResizeBuffers(0, p.cx, p.cy, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0); 
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    createTargetRender(w, h);
    return true;
}

void renderEditor()
{
    float color[] = { 0.36f, 0.36f, 0.36f, 1.0f }; 
    deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStancilBuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
    deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffer, color);

    swapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

P.S .: I also try to change the application using alt + tab. However, if the application is running in full screen, then it goes out of it. Why is that? And how to fix it? Thank.

P.S.S .: Sorry for my bad English ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I present the code and a small ReadMe.

**Code:**

```
// headers
#include <windows.h>

#include <d3d11.h>

#include <string>

// libraries
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")

// global variable
// dx
IDXGISwapChain* swapChain(nullptr);
ID3D11Device* device(nullptr);
ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext(nullptr);
ID3D11RenderTargetView* backBuffer(nullptr);
ID3D11Texture2D* DepthStancil(nullptr);
ID3D11DepthStencilView* DepthStancilBuffer(nullptr);
ID3D11RasterizerState* rasterizer(nullptr);
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth; 
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV; 
D3D11_VIEWPORT vp; 

// winapi
HWND hWnd;
HHOOK ExistingKeyboardProc;
HINSTANCE hInstance;
std::wstring className(L"Win32 DirectX");
WINDOWPLACEMENT fullscreenPlacement = { 0 };
WINDOWPLACEMENT windowedPlacement = { 0 };

// auxiliary
bool isRender(false); 

// governors variable
int height(600); // h window
int width(800); // w window
bool modeScreen(false); // mode screen(true - full screen, false - windowed mode)
bool enabelAltEnter(false); // enable mode alt + enter?(true - enable)

// constants windows message
#define WM_RENDER WM_USER + 1001

// functions
LRESULT WINAPI wndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void createDescsTarget();
bool createTargetRender();
bool renderStateEdit(const D3D11_FILL_MODE& fm);
int resizeWindow(SIZE p);
void renderEditor();
bool initDirectX();
bool hookKeyboardProc(HINSTANCE hinst);
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardProcLowLevel(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
int unHookKeyboardProc();
void clear();

// main
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, 
    HINSTANCE hPrev,                
    LPSTR szCmdLine,                
    int nShowCmd)                   
{
    hInstance = hInst;
    hookKeyboardProc(hInstance); // set keyboard hook

    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {0};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    wcx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcx.lpszClassName = (LPCSTR)className.c_str();

    if ( !RegisterClassEx(&wcx) ) 
        return 1;
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        (LPCSTR)className.c_str(),
        TEXT("Test going to full screen DirectX programm"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        300,300,
        width,height,
        0, 
        0,
        hInstance,
        0);

    if (!hWnd)    
        return 2;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

    if (!initDirectX())
        return 2;

    MSG msg;
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
        else
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_RENDER, NULL, NULL);
    }

    clear();

    return( (int)msg.wParam );  
}


// realisation all function's
LRESULT WINAPI wndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        SIZE p;
        p.cx = LOWORD(lParam);
        p.cy = HIWORD(lParam);
        std::string out = "size screen: " + std::to_string(p.cx) + ", " + std::to_string(p.cy) + "\n";
        OutputDebugStringA(out.c_str());
        if (resizeWindow(p) == -1)
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }

    case WM_RENDER:
        renderEditor();
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_HOME:
            {
                modeScreen = modeScreen ? false : true;
                if (modeScreen) 
                {
                    windowedPlacement.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
                    GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &windowedPlacement);
                }
                HRESULT hr = swapChain->SetFullscreenState(modeScreen, nullptr);
                if (hr != S_OK)
                    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
                if(!modeScreen) 
                    SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &windowedPlacement);
                break;
            }

        case VK_ESCAPE:
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        if (modeScreen && IsIconic(hWnd) && WA_ACTIVE == LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            isRender = true;
            SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &fullscreenPlacement);
            swapChain->SetFullscreenState(true, nullptr);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;

    } 
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

bool initDirectX()
{
    // init dx
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sdesc;
    ZeroMemory(&sdesc, sizeof(sdesc));
    sdesc.BufferCount = 1;
    sdesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    sdesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sdesc.Windowed = true;
    sdesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
    sdesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sdesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    sdesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sdesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };

    UINT flags(NULL);
#ifdef DEBUG
    flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT;
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL, flags, levels, 8, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sdesc,
        &swapChain, &device, NULL, &deviceContext);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;

    if (!enabelAltEnter) // disable mode alt + enter
    {
        IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
        HRESULT hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice);
        if (hr != S_OK)
            return false;

        IDXGIAdapter * pDXGIAdapter;
        hr = pDXGIDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void **)&pDXGIAdapter);
        if (hr != S_OK)
            return false;

        IDXGIFactory * pIDXGIFactory;
        hr = pDXGIAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)&pIDXGIFactory);
        if (hr != S_OK)
            return false;

        hr = pIDXGIFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(hWnd, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER);
        if (hr != S_OK)
            return false;
    }

    isRender = true;

    if (resizeWindow({ width, height }) == -1)
        return false;
    if (!renderStateEdit(D3D11_FILL_MODE::D3D11_FILL_SOLID))
        return false;

    hr = swapChain->SetFullscreenState(modeScreen, nullptr);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool hookKeyboardProc(HINSTANCE hinst)
{
    ExistingKeyboardProc = SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL, 
        keyboardProcLowLevel,
        hinst,
        NULL);  

    if (!ExistingKeyboardProc)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardProcLowLevel(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT * hookstruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)(lParam);

    switch (wParam)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        break;
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        if ((((hookstruct->flags) >> 5) & 1))
        {
            // ALT +
            switch (hookstruct->vkCode)
            {
            case VK_TAB: // ALT+TAB
            {
                if (modeScreen && !IsIconic(hWnd))
                {
                    isRender = false;
                    fullscreenPlacement.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
                    GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &fullscreenPlacement);
                    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE);
                    swapChain->SetFullscreenState(false, nullptr);
                }
            }
            break;
            case VK_RETURN: // ALT+ENTER
                break;
            case VK_ESCAPE: // ALT+ESC
                break;
            case VK_DELETE: // ALT+DEL
                break;
            };
        }
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        break;
    case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(ExistingKeyboardProc, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int unHookKeyboardProc()
{
    if (ExistingKeyboardProc)
    {
        BOOL retcode = UnhookWindowsHookEx((HHOOK)keyboardProcLowLevel);

        if (retcode)
        {
            // Successfully 
        }
        else
        {
            //Error 
        }
        return retcode;
    }
    else
    {
        //Error 
        return -1;
    }
}

void createDescsTarget()
{
    ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(descDepth));
    descDepth.Width = width;
    descDepth.Height = height;
    descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
    descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&descDSV, sizeof(descDSV));
    descDSV.Format = descDepth.Format;
    descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    vp.Width = (float)width;
    vp.Height = (float)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
}

bool createTargetRender()
{
    if (backBuffer)
        backBuffer->Release();
    if (DepthStancil)
        DepthStancil->Release();
    if (DepthStancilBuffer)
        DepthStancilBuffer->Release();

    HRESULT hr = swapChain->ResizeBuffers(0, 0,0, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;

    ID3D11Texture2D* texture(nullptr);
    hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&texture);
    hr = device->CreateRenderTargetView(texture, NULL, &backBuffer);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    texture->Release();

    createDescsTarget();

    hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &DepthStancil);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    hr = device->CreateDepthStencilView(DepthStancil, &descDSV, &DepthStancilBuffer);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;

    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backBuffer, DepthStancilBuffer);
    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);

    return true;
}

bool renderStateEdit(const D3D11_FILL_MODE& fm)
{
    if (rasterizer)
        rasterizer->Release();
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC wfd;
    ZeroMemory(&wfd, sizeof wfd);
    wfd.FillMode = fm;
    wfd.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    wfd.DepthClipEnable = true;
    HRESULT hr = device->CreateRasterizerState(&wfd, &rasterizer);
    if (hr != S_OK)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int resizeWindow(SIZE p)
{
    if (!isRender)
        return 0;
    if (IsIconic(hWnd))
        return 0;

    width = p.cx;
    height = p.cy;
    if (!createTargetRender())
        return -1;
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_RENDER, NULL, NULL);
    return 1;
}

void renderEditor()
{
    float color[] = { 0.36f, 0.36f, 0.36f, 1.0f }; 
    deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStancilBuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
    deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffer, color);

    swapChain->Present(0, 0);
}

void clear()
{
    if (swapChain)
        swapChain->Release();
    if (device)
        device->Release();
    if (deviceContext)
        deviceContext->Release();
    if (backBuffer)
        backBuffer->Release();
    if (DepthStancil)
        DepthStancil->Release();
    if (DepthStancilBuffer)
        DepthStancilBuffer->Release();
    if (rasterizer)
        rasterizer->Release();
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    UnregisterClass((LPCSTR)className.c_str(), hInstance);
}
```

**ReadMe:**

Keys:

- Escape key - exit
- Home key - change screen mode

Flags:

- modeScreen flag - true, run in full screen mode; false, run in
  windowed mode
- the enabelAltEnter flag is true, the alt + enter    combination works
  and switches the screen modes; false - the    combination does not
  work

Release:

- Minimize and Restore by Alt + Tab
- Block alt + enter
- Minimization and    correct recovery
- Resizing window mode

Solution: I had to call the function *ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd)* Before initializing DIrectX. And the alt + tab combination is made using hooks. I used C - style, but only for an example. Make classes is not difficult.